# Exclude empty lists from intersection in XQuery

Tags: xquery

I have several lists which may or may not be empty. I want to find those elements which occur in all lists, but only for those lists that are not empty.
I have something like this:

```
let $results := 
    $list1 intersect  
    $list2 intersect 
    $list3 intersect 
    $list4
```

But if any of the lists is empty this expression returns an empty list. Is there any way I can exclude a list from my intersection if it is empty?

**SOLUTION:**
This is the solution I ended up using, based on the answer provided by Ranon.

```
let $union := $list1 | $list2 | $list3 | $list4
let $results :=
    (if ($list1) then $list1 else $union)  intersect
    (if ($list2) then $list2 else $union)  intersect
    (if ($list3) then $list3 else $union)  intersect
    (if ($list4) then $list4 else $union)
```

I would like to thank all who have contributed. Coming from an object-oriented and procedural background, and with XQuery being a functional language it doesn't come as naturally to me (yet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check all lists if they're empty. If so, assign the union of all lists to them.

For my example I used the functx-implementation of intersect and union to be able to intersect sequences, too. Maybe one should write some function to avoid redundant code, but for showing the idea this code is fine:

```
import module namespace functx = "http://www.functx.com"  at ".../functx-1.0-nodoc-2007-01.xq";

let $list1 := (1,2,3)
let $list2 := (1,3)
let $list3 := ()
let $union := functx:value-union($list1, functx:value-union($list2, $list3))
let $list1a := if (count($list1) != 0) then $list1 else $union
let $list2a := if (count($list2) != 0) then $list2 else $union
let $list3a := if (count($list3) != 0) then $list3 else $union
return functx:value-intersect($list1a, functx:value-intersect($list2a, $list3a))
```

`$union` could also be written as `($list1, $list2, $list3)`, but that will lead to double elements which result in slower intersection-operations for large element counts.

Comment: Hi Ranon. I tested this and it works great. I just re-wrote it to use regular union and intersection (since I actually want to check on identity) and I also simply test on existence rather then on count. I've updated the question with my code.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the builtin `intersect` directly, you can wrap it in a function and check the input lists:

```
declare function local:safe-intersect($xs, $ys) {
  if(exists($xs) and exists($ys))
  then $xs intersect $ys
  else ($xs, $ys) (: at least one is empty :)
};
```

Then your example would look like this:

```
let $results := 
    local:safe-intersect(
      $list1,
      local:safe-intersect(
        $list2,
        local:safe-intersect($list3, $list4)
      )
    )
...
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
       ( $vL1 |   ($vL2 | $vL3 | $vL4)[not($vL1)] )
  intersect
       ( $vL2 |   ($vL3 | $vL4 | $vL1)[not($vL2)] )
  intersect
       ( $vL3 |   ($vL4 | $vL1 | $vL2)[not($vL3)] )
 intersect
      ( $vL4 |   ($vL1 | $vL2 | $vL3)[not($vL4)] )
```

In this expression every argument of `intersect` is either a `$vN` or, if `$vN` is empty, it is the union of the rest of the sets.

**This can be written more compactly as**:

```
let $vUniverse := $vL1 | $vL2 | $vL3 | $vL4
  return
            ( $vL1 |   $vUniverse [not($vL1)] )
      intersect
            ( $vL2 |   $vUniverse [not($vL2)] )
      intersect
            ( $vL3 |   $vUniverse [not($vL3)] )
     intersect
            ( $vL4 |   $vUniverse [not($vL4)] )
```

**Here is a complete example**:

```
let $vL1 := /*/*[. mod 2 eq 1],
    $vL2 := /*/*[. mod 3 eq 1],
    $vL3 := /*/*[. mod 4 eq 1],
    $vL4 := /*/*[. mod 5 eq 1],
    $vUniverse := $vL1 | $vL2 | $vL3 | $vL4
   return
        ( $vL1 |   $vUniverse [not($vL1)] )
      intersect
        ( $vL2 |   $vUniverse [not($vL2)] )
      intersect
        ( $vL3 |   $vUniverse [not($vL3)] )
     intersect
        ( $vL4 |   $vUniverse [not($vL4)] )
```

**when this XQuery expression is evaluated (using Saxon 9.3.04 EE) on the following XML document:**

```
 <nums>
    <num>01</num>
    <num>02</num>
    <num>03</num>
    <num>04</num>
    <num>05</num>
    <num>06</num>
    <num>07</num>
    <num>08</num>
    <num>09</num>
    <num>10</num>
 </nums>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<num>01</num>
```

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? I thought that this solution looked most elegant, but upon some closer inspection it seems that the result would end up being a union of all lists. A test confirmed my suspicion.

Comment: @NobleK: Yes, I always test my code by actually running it. I updated my answer with a complete code example, showing this in action. The reason for your problem may be that you didn't copy and paste the code completely and that you omitted the brackets. The brackets are important, because `interscect` has higher priority than `union`.

Comment: It wasn't my intention to insult you or anything. I have read some of your answers on XQuery here at SO before, and I do believe that you know what you are talking about. It’s just that your approach really doesn’t seem to work for me (and yes, I did remember all the brackets). I suspect that it might have something to do with the eXist XQuery engine that I am using. I have noticed it behaving strange on occasions and producing different results than Saxon.

Comment: @NobleK: NP, then the eXist devs would appreciate if you share your observations. When you run my code example, don't you get the same result as I get?